# Android Studio Advice

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

On my Android Studio, it says it "cannot resolve R symbol." So I tried rebuilding it and cleaning it several times, but it's still like this.

What do I do?

Here's my code- The first url shows my code

[image]

My gradle says these two things are the problem, but I don't understand it. Here's what my gradle says:

[image]

Comment: If rebuilding and cleaning does not fix your problem, you might have an error on any xml file/s, unabling R to renderize. Please check them out

Comment: down grade your appcompat to  compileSdkVersion  in build gradle file

Comment: maybe you need to import R -- click on R -- do you see an underline saying Import?? in your imports do you have  eg (import com.myProject.R;) ??

Comment: can you add a screenshot of values.xml

Answer (score 0):

This happens quite often to me too. I usually end up going File> Invalidate Caches and Restart which fixes it 99% of the time

Answer (score 0):

In your `activity_horizontal_margin` you are probably referencing a string from `values.xml` which doesn't exist, make sure use `@+id/....` when this is a new value not declared in `values.xml` and are instructing the parser (or call it the builder) to create a new entry in `R.java`, thus you have to include a + sign.,use  `@id/...` when you want to reference an already existing resource in `values.xml`  so parser links this to the already created id in `R.java`. you can now rebuild your project.

Answer (score 0):

1) Please check buildToolsVersion or downgrade it.
2)  make sure your appcompat compile library is included in build.gradle 
3) Try to restart Android studio with invalid caches and restart
4) clean/rebuild project and then synch it.

Hope it helps